# xamarin.forms - how to disable shading/color change on tap and hold of a ViewCell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have disabled selection of ViewCells using the below, and it worked--ViewCells no longer become selected:

```
MyListView.ItemSelected += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
};
```

However, ViewCells still flash with a gray color when tapped, and also turn the same gray color if they are tapped and held.

How can this color change on tap be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to use a renderer

For iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CardCell), typeof(CardCellRenderer))]
namespace Foo
{
    public class CardCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50783/how-i-can-disable-highlight-item-in-listview)

I have noticed that if your list view makes use of `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` this can cause issues